# Use Node from Homebrew instead of vanilla Node

Tags: node.js, homebrew

Using Mac OS.

Tried updating Node because of the recent security patch. Ran "node -v" in terminal, got v10.(something before the 10.19.0), tried to update via Homebrew, gave me a warning saying I already had v13.8.0 (which is the one needed for the v13). Realized I must have installed twice, manually removed all files I could following https://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/.

tried node -v, now it's giving me an error "Error: Unknown command: node"

I didn't touch any of the files in the Homebrew directories, and it still shows (after restarting computer) the v13 if I do brew commands.

How do I get the terminal to recognize and use the v13 from Homebrew?

(still new to developing, so I'm not entirely sure I phrased this right)

Comment: `brew link node`? You could also look into [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

Comment: Just used it. Thank you!